# Can't change value of react-select field

Tags: reactjs, onchange, react-select

I am using the React-Select library for my React app select fields. I have the same form for adding and editing data. If I don't provide any value, it works just fine, but if I want to have default values when the app renders, I can't change them. They appear as selected, but if I try to select another option it just doesn't update and the value I provided in `value` prop remains selected.

I tried using `defaultValue` instead of `value`, but then it doesn't select anything when the app renders.

```
<Select 
    placeholder="Deposit"
    options={deposits}
    getOptionValue={ option =>
        option["id"]
    }
    getOptionLabel={ option => {
        return option["name"];
    }}
    onChange={ value => {
        this.setState({ deposit_id: value.id }}
    value={{
        value: deposit_id || "",
        name: deposit_name || ""
    }}
/>
```

`deposits` is an array of objects, and it renders the list of names, but when I click on one of them, the one that I provided in `value` remains selected, but it should select the one that I click on... How do I change it? Is there something wrong with my `onChange` function? Or what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of `react-select` are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code. The value props should be a string, i.e the value from the state.

```
<Select 
    placeholder="Deposit"
    options={deposits}
    getOptionValue={ option =>
        option["id"]
    }
    getOptionLabel={ option => {
        return option["name"];
    }}
    onChange={ value => {
        this.setState({ deposit_id: value.id }}
    value={deposit_id}
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. It doesn't select anything using this, not event the value that I provide, nor the one that I selecte after that... Thank you tho for your time :)